# How to post and bind json data without specifying objectname in WCF service

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I have a service below

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "/PostData")]
 public string GetImage(MyData data)
        {
            return "success";l
        }
```

Data contract is :

```
[DataContract]
public class MyData 
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Base64String { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int ID{ get; set; }
}
```

but while posing json data I must specify format like :

```
{
"data":
{
"Base64String": "my base 64 string",
"ID":"1"
}
}
```

but My requirement is to post data without object name(instance name), so I want json like

```
{
"Base64String": "my base 64 string",
"ID":"1"
}
```

Is there any way to get it work in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe if you change the `BodyStyle` property of the `WebInvoke` attribute to `WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare` [this might work](http://www.wcf.dotnetarchives.com/2013/12/difference-between-webmessagebodystylew.html).

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "/PostData")]
public string GetImage(MyData data)
{
    return "success";
}
```